# Facing issue using QAF common step og click and clear methods

Tags: qaf

Facing some weird issue when using QAF common steps. We just facing in “I click” and “I clear” methods so far.

Step to reproduce:
Step: And I click on "LOGIN_btn||rt.loc.e8R5BmyEUI"

```
@QAFTestStep(description = "I click on {0}")
public static void iClick(String locator) throws Exception {
click(locator);
}
```

**Result: Fail**

Issue: Unable to locate login button.

Here, Element locator is absolutely fine and if I change method name like “iClickOn” or “iClickABC” like below then its working fine as expected.

```
   @QAFTestStep(description = "I click on {0}")
    public static void iClickOn(String locator) throws Exception {
    click(locator);
    }
```

**Result: Pass**

Another approach is also working fine. If I removed “On” from step then its working fine.
Step: And I click "LOGIN_btn||rt.loc.e8R5BmyEUI"

```
@QAFTestStep(description = "I click {0}")
public static void iClick(String locator) throws Exception {
click(locator);
}
```

**Result: Pass**
Note: Same issue I'm facing in I clear locator as well.
Kindly check and confirm is there any restriction to use words in steps or what could be the problem here.

Comment: What is `step.provider.pkg` value you have provided? The reason may be step loaded from different package. Can you share `step.provider.pkg` value you are using?

Comment: step.provider.pkg=com.rt.steps   // Note: All steps are written in the following directory: src/test/java/com/rt/steps

Comment: Yes. As Renish mentioned, we are using step.provider.pkg=com.rt.steps in applicati.properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check all entries of `step.provider.pkg`. Most probably the reason is you have another library specifying step with same name with same description and step loaded from it.

For example if you are using Perfecto-Quantum it has [step](https://github.com/Perfecto-Quantum/Quantum/blob/dd3885a1ac0b7808e3d9c2fb23f3a5fe9bd4c8c4/src/main/java/com/quantum/steps/PerfectoApplicationSteps.java#L354) with same name and description. The simplest way to find out is editor content-assist in IDE. You will see all available step definitions in content assist.

Comment: Thanks. We have some duplicate entries in another file.